# Split String using regex in java

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to regex, What i'm trying to do is to split the String with certain conditions but i don't know how to do it.

Here is the sample/condition

```
String str = sum1=x+(5+a)

Array[0] = sum1
Array[1] = =
Array[2] = x
Array[3] = +
Array[4] = (
Array[5] = 5
Array[6] = +
Array[7] = a
Array[8] = )
```

I want the string to be split by `+`,`-`,`*`,`\`,`(`,`)`,`=`
Is this possible?

Comment: yes it is very possible, but i dont understand why you have an array?

if you had just a string (not an array) you could do string.split?

also you would want to split the string using a digit/non digit split string regex

Comment: hopefully you don't want to do order of operation stuff because otherwise you're barking up the wrong tree

Comment: Sounds like it's time to make tokens and parse them.

Comment: You can do this with regex, but it is not a good fit for regex. (I have attempted to build a calculator entirely out of regexes and substring, but it is incredibly difficult to prove it is bug-free, especially if you later extend it. I do not recommend that approach.) It looks like you want to build a tokenizer/parser that can perform calculations: http://java-source.net/open-source/parser-generators

Comment: I'm trying to develop tokenizer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you **really** need to use regex you should probably use [look-around](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) mechanism since you don't want to split *at* this characters, but *before* or *after* them.

```
String str = "sum1=x+(5+a)";
String[] array=str.replaceAll("\\s+","")//remove all spaces
                  .split("(?<=[+\\-*\\\\()=/])|(?=[+\\-*\\\\()=/])");
for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
    System.out.println("Array["+i+"] = "+array[i]);
```

output:

```
Array[0] = sum1
Array[1] = =
Array[2] = x
Array[3] = +
Array[4] = (
Array[5] = 5
Array[6] = +
Array[7] = a
Array[8] = )
```

Comment: You seems have other way in mind.Is their way other than using regex?

Comment: @newbie If it is just for this simple tokenization regex will be enough. But maybe you should consider other ways of sorting/creating tokens so it would be easier to calculate your string later like [reverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation) / [Polish notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polish_notation)

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible the regex would look like this `yourstring.split("[\+\-\*\\\(\)\=]")`

Comment: Won't this destroy WHICH token you're splitting on, though?

Comment: yes, maybe I can split on a non capturing group, like a split with a zero width assertion